# Access to protected copy ctor in Base

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, intellisense

The following snippet is accepted by GCC and MSVC but Intellisense (EDG) complains:

```
class Base {
protected:
    Base(Base const&) { }
};


class Derived : public Base {
// Error: protected function Base::base(const Base&) ... is not accessible
// through a "Base" pointer or object.
public:
    Derived(Derived const& src) = default;
};
```

Weirdly enough, the equivalent code `: Base(src) { }` is accepted.

Is Intellisense right to reject the defaulted copy ctor?

Comment: The code appears correct (no problem with clang for example), looks like a compiler bug. What happens if `Base::Base(Base const&)` is `=default`?

Comment: i don't get any errors whatsoever with VS2013 update 4. what version are you using?

Comment: I have never heard of a  case where Intellisense is right where a compiler is wrong. The reverse is quite frequent, though.

Comment: Intellisense is often mistakenly right when it comes to parsing templates

Comment: Intellisense is an EDG compiler nowadays, which is far closer to the Standard. Its main problem is working on half-complete code, which is unfortunate for auto-complete (which by definition works on incomplete code). The red underlining of errors is generally OK.

Comment: Odd: ICC 13.0.1 (an EDG compiler as well, AIUI) [accepts this code](http://goo.gl/oM5Kzi)

Comment: clang version 3.7.0 (trunk 230615) also accepts this code.